# How to send multiple file(image) names to database and also fetch all image uploaded by a user

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to php. I have a form where user can register with his data.
    Here i gave extra option he also can upload multiple image. Multiple images  are uploading to their path. Here  I want send their name to database to and fetch all multiple images uploaded by a user.

Here is my code for multiple file.

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file[]" value="Upload">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

    for ($i=0; $i <$total; $i++) { 
        $tmpfile= $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

        if ($tmpfile != ""){
            $newFilePath = "image/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpfile, $newFilePath)) {
                echo "Upload successfully";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my database details.

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", '', 'multiple');
$query = "insert into image_upload(image_name) values('$newFilePath')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Here i want send to all image names to database and fetch all images by name. 
Can any one help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", '', 'multiple');
    $total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $imageArr=array();
    for ($i=0; $i <$total; $i++) { 
        $tmpfile= $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

        if ($tmpfile != ""){
            $newFilePath = "image/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpfile, $newFilePath)) {
                $query = "insert into image_upload(image_name) values ('$newFilePath')";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                $imageArr[$i]=$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                if($i=$total) {
                    echo "Upload successfully";
                }

            }
        }
    }
    print_r($imageArr);
}
```

Hope this will help you.